# Ansible Substring From List Item

Tags: ansible

To keep this simple, I have one whitelist directory, one directory being passed in.   I need to make sure the full directory of "/tmp/dir1/dir2" FAILS, where a directory of "/local/web/dir1" SUCCEEDS.

This code, always says it's good.  No matter what I pass.  What am I missing?

**EDIT**
First of all {{ dir }} is passed in, it's all running under AaaS.   Data passed in looks like:

**should succeed:**

```
/local/web/test1/dir1
```

**should fail:**

```
/home/test
```

**ansible-playbook-yml**

```
---
- name: Generate Directory Structure and by list.
  hosts: target_hosts
  vars:
    dir: {{ dir }}
    whitelist_dir:
      - "/local/web"

  tasks:
    - name: Validate Search {{ dir }}
      debug:
        msg: "directory is good!"
      when: item is search(dir)
      with_items:
        - "{{ whitelist_dir }}"
```

Comment: A snippet of what? A playbook?: it's missing a `tasks` stanza and the indentation is not correct. A task list?: the first task is not valid as it contains no action. How are you launching all this ? How are you passing the value to the `dir` variable ? Can you show what it looks like exactly with a debug ? Besides the fact you have (from what I understand) switched your terms in your when clause (i.e. it should be `when: dir is search(item)` - but maybe this is a copy paste error when putting up your snippet....), your test should work. It would be much easier to be sure with an MCVE

Comment: Since you can't read snippets, does that help?   And yes, this is an ansible-playbook.yml

Comment: Can I ask why you are so aggressive ? Yes this definitely helps to understand how you are launching your tasks and to rule out any other errors. I have helped many people having similar problems linked to yaml/playbook/task syntax/indentation problems. I already pointed out in my last comment that your `when` clause has reversed parameters. Did you try the other way around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your edit and my last comment, the only real problem I see is that you reversed your parameters in your where clause (although it does not explain IMO why it would always succeed...).

If I check with parameters in the right order, I get the result you expect. I even added a second whitelist path in the following MCVE to make sure your loop was working correctly. The following `test.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Check if directory is in whitelist path
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: dir
      prompt: Type in full path you want to check
      private: no

  vars:
    whitelist_dir:
      - "/local/web"
      - "/toto/pipo"

  tasks:
    - name: Validate Search {{ dir }}
      debug:
        msg: "directory is good!"
      when: dir is search(item)
      with_items:
        - "{{ whitelist_dir }}"
```

Gives (3 differents tests)

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
Type in full path you want to check: /local/web/test1/dir1

PLAY [Check if directory is in whitelist path] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Validate Search /local/web/test1/dir1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/local/web) => {
    "msg": "directory is good!"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/toto/pipo) 

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0 

$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
Type in full path you want to check: /home/test

PLAY [Check if directory is in whitelist path] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Validate Search /home/test] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/local/web) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/toto/pipo) 
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
Type in full path you want to check: /toto/pipo/test.txt

PLAY [Check if directory is in whitelist path] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Validate Search /toto/pipo/test.txt] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/local/web) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=/toto/pipo) => {
    "msg": "directory is good!"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: ok, so it looks like I just had "dir" and "item" backwards.   How do you run ansible?  I work for a corporation, so I have to jump through hoops to get it on a server, so I can even test it.   I installed CentOS with Ansible on my personal machine, but every time I run ansible-playbook, I get an error stating Python doesn't exist.  I have Python2 and Python3 installed, but ansible doesn't want to run those.  Tried installing Python and it states, it doesn't exist, install Python2 and Python3 instead.   By the way, thanks for contributing.  I'm fairly new to ansible and no sandbox to play in.

Comment: I usually install ansible through pip, nowadays in python3: `pip(3) install ansible`. This is by far the most flexible and most up-to-date install option as you can install globally for all users (as root), individually for each user on the system or in any number of virtualenv you wish. If you installed on centos with yum, chances are you have an outdated version. I suggest you simply remove it and install with pip instead: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-with-pip

Comment: I had pip install ansible, but it errored telling me there are problems with this version and to use pip install ansible-base.

Comment: just installed using pip install ansible again.  Seem to still get the same error. /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

Comment: I can create a new question with this issue, so you can get the points for it.

Comment: just found the answer and it seems to work..  ha.
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

Comment: I can install on fresh centos 7 and 8 inside docker without any problem: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/4074dac9003ff8605d8b9a076df4802c. You might have a configuration issue on your install/vm.

Comment: I'm not using docker.  Is there a need to use docker?   I'm able to run ansible-playbook main.yml but then I have to put the full path to the YML again and it runs it, showing me the results.

Comment: [WARNING]: You are running the development version of Ansible. You should only run Ansible from "devel" if you are modifying the Ansible engine, or trying out features under development.
This is a rapidly changing source of code and can become unstable at any point.

Comment: If you look at my example installs above, the version installed is 2.9.11 in both cases which is the latest supported and not devel (2.10.x). You must have tempered with your pip config somehow to let install the devel version

Comment: I deleted the ansible folder, did a "git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive --branch devel" and I still get the warning.    I'm thinking of blowing it all away and reinstalling from scratch.   Took a lot of steps to get to this point, some might of messed something up.

Comment: I am running on VMWare, if that makes a difference, not sure.

Comment: Absolutely none for the current concern (i.e. installing/running ansible) as long as your system is correctly installed. Try superuser.com and serverfault.com for this type of questions.

Comment: I've reinstalled everything, leaving 90% of what I had to do out and it works beautifully.  Thanks